# Unable to install react-scripts via npm install

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am new to node and react, i am trying to create a react app using
npx create-react-app sample
while creating the app, npm is trying to install the react-scripts module and its failing with the following error

```
4967 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
4968 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
4969 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
4969 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
4969 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
4969 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
4970 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
4971 warn notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
4972 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid OS:    darwin
4972 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Valid Arch:  any
4972 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual OS:   win32
4972 verbose notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Actual Arch: x64
4973 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...rollup-1.12.5.tgz","f'
4973 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
4973 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Software\node-v12.13.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
4973 verbose stack     at C:\Software\node-v12.13.1-win-x64\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
4973 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
4973 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
4974 verbose cwd C:\Personal\Learning\react
4975 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19042
4976 verbose argv "C:\\Software\\node-v12.13.1-win-x64\\node.exe" "C:\\Software\\node-v12.13.1-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "react-scripts"
4977 verbose node v12.13.1
4978 verbose npm  v6.12.1
4979 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...rollup-1.12.5.tgz","f'
4980 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

i searched in google with error i am not able to find the solutions,
Steps i have taken to fix the problem

1. npm cache clean
2. tried to install the react-scripts globally
3. removed the proxy in npm config and tried to install

none of those things worked

Comment: Run this command prompt as Administrator role in windows or if using mac or linux then give the root permission and try

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend upgrading your node.js and then try npm install again:

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n stable
npm install
```